# How to transform value in JSON array using JOLT?

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "X1"
  },
  ...
  {
    "key": "X100"
  }
]
```

I need to write JOLT transformation which'll replace "X20" with "Z". Of course numbers 20 and 100 could be different so the transformation should be generic enough. I mean the value to replace might occur at different position at the array but its name is always "X20". Could you please provide me some insight?

I've tried to write some transformations but without bigger successes and
read similar topics.

@edit
Thanks for your reply! What if my array is injected in other json array as follows? So I want to transform the inner `array` as I've described at the beggining?

I wanted to use your solution into my context but it is not straightforward (at least for me...).

```json
[
  {
    "id": "4",
    "array": [
      {
        "key": "X1",
        "key2": "some_value1_1"
      },
      {
        "key": "X2",
        "key2": "some_value1_2"
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "array": [
      {
        "key": "X1",
        "key2": "some_value2_1"
      },
       {
        "key": "X2",
        "key2": "some_value2_2"
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional which distinguishes among the values of the `"key"`s such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": {
          "X20": { "#Z": "[&3].&2" },
          "*": { "@1": "[&3].&2" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

***Edit*** : the following specification will handle your last, edited case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "array": {
          "*": {
            "key": {
              "X20": { "#Z": "[&5].&4[&3].&2" },
              "*": { "@1": "[&5].&4[&3].&2" }
            },
            "*": "[&3].&2[&1].&" // else case in which
                                 // reduce the degrees of 
                                 // upper identifiers by 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated my question, because it turned out it is not so easy to inject this solution into my real case.

Comment: @PeterZof Kindly you can accept the answer if you find it helpful, thanks.